How can I prevent the maicontent from falling behind when the fixed sidemenu is opened?
i want to make react collapsible side menu. I have shared the codes of 3 components below. I need the side menu to remain fixed as the scroll increases, but when I set a fixed value, the content is hidden behind. The problem is that when the menu opens, the words header and section stay behind and are not visible. how can i prevent this
If there is another easy way, you can advise me, thanks in advance
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <header>this is a header</header>
    </header>
  );
};

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Sidebar = ({ children }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  const menuItem = [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Dashboard",
    },
    {
      path: "/about",
      name: "About",
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div style={{ width: isOpen ? "200px" : "50px" }} className="sidebar">
        <div className="top_section">
          <h1 style={{ display: isOpen ? "block" : "none" }} className="logo">
            Logo
          </h1>
          <div style={{ marginLeft: isOpen ? "50px" : "0px" }} className="bars">
            <button onClick={toggle}>=</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        {menuItem.map((item, index) => (
          <NavLink
            to={item.path}
            key={index}
            className="link"
            activeclassName="active"
          >
            <div className="icon">{item.icon}</div>
            <div
              style={{ display: isOpen ? "block" : "none" }}
              className="link_text"
            >
              {item.name}
            </div>
          </NavLink>
        ))}
      </div>
      <main>{children}</main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;


Router
  <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Sidebar>
          <Routes>
            <Route element={<Home />} path="/" />
            <Route element={<About />} path="/about" />
          </Routes>
        </Sidebar>
      </BrowserRouter>


Css 
.sidebar{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.container{
    display:flex;
}
main{
    width: 100%;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
}


